# Open window (modal or otherwise) from a link and loading it with data from the code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

So I have something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[8] 
            { 
                new DataColumn("Foto",typeof(string)),
                //more columns
            });

            List<Funcion> fun = Festival.Instancia.ListaFunciones;
            List<Espectaculo> esp = Festival.Instancia.ListaEspectaculos;
            List<Sala> sala = Festival.Instancia.ListaSalas;

            foreach (Funcion f in fun)
            {
                string nom = f.Espectaculo;
                string fec = f.Fecha.Day.ToString() + "/" + f.Fecha.Month.ToString();
                string hor = f.HoraIni.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                string sal = f.Sala;
                Espectaculo es = Festival.Instancia.BuscarEspectaculo(nom);
                Sala s = Festival.Instancia.BuscarSala(f.Sala);
                string com = es.Cnia;
                string pais = es.Pais;
                string dir = s.DirSala;
                string foto = es.Foto;

                dt.Rows.Add(foto, nom, fec, hor, sal, dir, com, pais);
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
}}
```

...and the markup to show it. I need to show just a few of those columns on a gridview, where I also have a link button in the markup. The idea would be to open a new window, or a modal (modal would be great) that is dinamically generated with data from all of those, like a details view. Thing is, I cannot write each window separately, since the user can add to the lists above, so those have to be generated at runtime. When doing that with Javascript/jQuery, so far I can only show data that is already present in the grid, and I can't make it hidden in the view and showing in the modal... Id like to be able to do that server-side.

Not sure if I'm being clear...

EDIT:

Here's the markup with the client-side script I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "[id*=lnkDetalles]", function () {
    $("#foto").html($(".Foto", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
    $("#espectaculo").html($(".Espectaculo", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
   //more columns
    $("#detalles").dialog({
        title: "Detalles",
        buttons: {
            Cerrar: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

   <h1 runat="server" id="mensaje"></h1>



<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Foto" HeaderText="Foto" ItemStyle-CssClass="Foto" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Foto"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Espectaculo" ItemStyle-CssClass="Espectaculo" HeaderText="Espectaculo" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Espectáculo"/>
//more columns
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Detalles" ID="lnkDetalles" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
<div id="detalles" style="display: none">
<span id="foto"></span>
Espectaculo:<span id="espectaculo"></span>
<br />
Fecha:<span id="fecha"></span>
<br />
Hora:<span id="hora"></span>
<br />
Sala:<span id="sala"></span>
<br />
Direccion:<span id="dir"></span>
<br />
Compañía:<span id="cnia"></span>
<br />
Pais:<span id="pais"></span>
<br />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

This is working quite fine, but I would like to NOT need to show every field in the GridView and still be able to use the data in the modal window, like hiding a column but still have it show in the details view.

Comment: So what's your problem? How is it not working as expected?

Comment: you sure are trying to accomplish a lot here in a single method.. also what the heck is going on in these lines 
`GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();` you're binding looks off format the code too

Comment: @DJKRAZE `GridView1.DataSource = dt; GridView1.DataBind();` is how you bind a DataTable to a GridView from code behind.

Comment: I can show the data in a modal windo using jQuery, but only data that is already present and visible in the GridView. I would like to be able to call on some of the fields on the datatable to show them WITHOUT having to show them on the GridView.

Comment: I know that `Mason` but look at how he's doing it.. in a foreach loop.. that's what looks off.. what if there are more than 8 values  I would expect the Binding to be out side of the foreach loop

Comment: @DJKRAZE Then point that out in your original comment. Your original comment makes it sound like those lines are out of the ordinary, rather than just in the wrong place.

Comment: @dumber_than_thou Assuming your GridView is showing up properly in a modal, then I don't see why it isn't working. You haven't provided your client side code for how you're putting it in a modal in your question. That's probably crucial to understanding what you're doing wrong.

Comment: So... should I take it out of the loop? It is working fine that way, but I wondered that myself. Also added the markup and the modal code.

Comment: Yes, you should take the DataSource and DataBind stuff out of the loop, you only need to do it once (after the loop has completed).

Comment: Ok, done. Still no idea on the other thing, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place anything you want to appear in the modal inside `detalles`.

```
<div id="detalles" style="display: none">
    Espectaculo: <asp:Label id="EspectaculoLbl" runat="server" />
</div>
```

In your page load method, you'd just do this:

```
EspectaculoLbl.Text = "Hola, mundo!"; //instead of setting it to hardcoded string, load it from the database
```

Comment: And how do I reference that one instead of the original one? Also, if I do that, how do I avoid having it show on the modal window?

Comment: What do you mean "avoid having it show on the modal window"? You do want the GridView to be in the modal window, right?

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't mark this as answered before, I was sure I had. Better late than never, I guess.